# Angular 2 (Ionic 2) call a function in a page when ever page is displayed

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular, ecmascript-6, ionic2

When ever my home page in **`angular 2(ionic 2)`** app is loaded I want call service/function. How to achieve this?

For the first time when the app is loaded(home page is loaded) I can  write this in the **`constructor`**, but when user start using the app and **`push`** new pages into **`nav controller`** and **`pop`** them to come back to **`home page`**, the **`constructor`** wont get called again.

#### I am stuck here.

I would like to know what is the best way to achieve this feature?

I am new to **`angular2`** and **`ionic2`** **`framework`** (also don't have experiences in **`angular1`** and **`ionic1`**), please help me out.

Many Many Thanks.

## update

### sample code of what I tried, but didn't worked.

```
import {Page, NavController, Platform, Storage, SqlStorage} from 'ionic-angular';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/page1/page1.html'
})
export class Page1 {
    static get parameters(){
        return [[NavController],[Platform]];
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("Showing the first page!");
    }
    constructor(nav, platform){
        this.nav = nav;
        this.platform =  platform;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**`onPageWillEnter()`** worked for me.

```
import {Page, NavController, Platform, Storage, SqlStorage} from 'ionic-angular';


@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/page1/page1.html'
})
export class Page1 {
    static get parameters(){
        return [[NavController],[Platform]];
    }
    onPageWillEnter() {
        console.log("Showing the first page!");
    }
    constructor(nav, platform){
        this.nav = nav;
        this.platform =  platform;
    }
}
```

[**Ionic lifecycle hook**](https://webcake.co/page-lifecycle-hooks-in-ionic-2/)

Answer (score 6):

**IONIC 2 RC1** Update

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    console.log("this function will be called every time you enter the view");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the [lifeCycle-hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html), specifically `ngOnInit()` or `ngAfterViewInit()`.

[Here](http://learnangular2.com/lifecycle/) is a simple tutorial.

**For Example:**

```
// Annotation section
@Component({
  selector: 'street-map',
  template: '<map-window></map-window><map-controls></map-controls>',
})
// Component controller
class StreetMap {
  ngOnInit() {  //here you can call the function wanted
    // Properties are resolved and things like
    // this.mapWindow and this.mapControls
    // had a chance to resolve from the
    // two child components <map-window> and <map-controls>
  }
}
```

**Update:** it works for pure `Angular2` applications, for `IonicFramework` specific solution see

*@DeepakChandranP's* answer.

Comment: I tried this, and seen in the tutorial also, but seems to be this function `ngOnInit()` is not getting called. - updated my question with code.

Comment: I think I have to use `onPageLoaded()` in my case. Let me try and come back.

Comment: Yes, its `onPageWillEnter()`

Comment: Nice to know. But it looks like it's not part of Angular, probably Ionic's own implementation.